# Using PIC PORT address in a struct

Tags: pointers, struct, microcontroller, pic18

I was trying to pass PORTs address trough a struct by using a function, by i don't know how to correct work with pointers. Here's the code of my struct and function:

```
typedef struct {
read:1;
last_read:1;
changed:1;
unsigned short *port;    //Here the declaration of the pointer that will receive the address
pin:1;
active_state:1;
} Input;

void Setup_input(Input s,char *port, char pin, char active_state){
 s.port = &port;        //HERE I TRY TO PASS THE ADDRESS OF THE PORT TO THE POINTER OBJECT
 s.pin = pin;
 s.active_state = active_state;
```

It turns out that I'm not doing it correctly and I'm not able to read or control correctly the PORT. I'm using Mikroelectronic PRO compilers.

Comment: When you program microcontrollers it's recommended that you have passed the learning of the C language.

Comment: You should really add a type, i.e. `unsigned int` to those bitfields. A 1-bit `int` is a bad idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line of code

```
s.port = &port;
```

stores the address of the parameter into the member `port`. When you dereference the pointer in the structure you will access the stack memory where the parameter `port` were while calling `Setup_input()`. This causes undefined behavior.

What you obviously want is to assigne the value of the parameter:

```
s.port = port;
```

Comment: If i just fix that line could i use the member s.port as the original PORT was? i mean, could i read, write the PORT just using this member?

Comment: Yes, if you fixed your code than you use a copy of the pointer. As long as the data width is the same, it's okay.

Comment: thank you a lot, i fixed a part, but i realized that my problem is with the struct argumento from mu function, if you look, my function is receiving the struct that i want to edit, but i think the function is creating a copy of the struct a pass to it. I need to someway pass a pointer of the orginal struct, so i could edit every struct i put in the funcion. do you know how can i declare a function with struct pointer?

Comment: `void Setup_input(Input *s, char *port, char pin, char active_state)` -- Frankly, buy a good C book (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list/562377#562377). It makes much more fun to program microcontrollers if you can distinguish between a C language problem and a microcontroller problem.